# Wordpress change order on click

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

**I have use this code on search.php page to get post from oldest to newest and oldest to newest according to link click

Note: But now my Default search form is not working on this page**

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'order' => (isset($_GET['orderby']) ? $_GET['orderby'] : 'ASC')
);
query_posts($args);
?>

<div class="sort_by">
  <span>Sort by:</span>
  <span class="relevance <?php if(!isset($_GET['order'])){ echo 'activesearch';} ?>"><a href="?s=<?php echo $_GET['s']; ?>">Relevance</a></span>
  <span class="newest <?php if(isset($_GET['order']) && $_GET['order']=='DESC'){ echo 'activesearch';}else{ echo '';} ?>"><a href="?s=<?php echo $_GET['s']; ?>&orderby=post_date&order=DESC" >Newest</a></span>
  <span class="oldest <?php if(isset($_GET['order']) && $_GET['order']== 'ASC'){ echo 'activesearch';}else{ echo '';} ?>"><a href="?s=<?php echo $_GET['s']; ?>&&orderby=post_date&order=ASC">Oldest</a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you using `query_posts()` you should save origin query. Something like this should help you.

```
global $wp_query;
query_posts(
    array_merge(
        array('orderby' => 'DESC', 'order'=> 'date'),
        $wp_query->query
    )
);
```

or

```
global $query_string;
parse_str($query_string, $args);
$args['orderby'] = 'date';
$args['order'] = 'DESC';
query_posts( $args );
```